# How to identify a max number in an array but not if two or more numbers are tied to be max numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a game where 4 dices are rolled and the highest number wins. I am putting the data in an array and using `Array.max` to find out which is the highest. However, if 2 or 3 dices are tied I can't do this. Is there a way to identify tie? Thanks

Comment: You can remove the highest value from the array, then see if the new maximum remains the same. If not, it was unique.

Comment: @ChrisG Good idea, I will try that

Comment: `array.filter(x => x == max).length > 1` then it is tie.

Comment: To be clear, if you roll `3,4,6,6` then max is `4`? So I presume if you roll `3,3,5,5` max is `0`? Or should that be `1` since `0` is not a die number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this logic:

```js
let diceScores = [2,6,5,6];
let maxScore = Math.max(...diceScores);
diceScores.filter(x => x === maxScore).length > 1 ? console.log('tie') :console.log('no tie');
```

Comment: Thank you I can use this. But I don't understand the `x => x === maxScore` what does this mean?

Comment: You are welcome.`x => x === maxScore` is a _lambda expression_ and serves as a callback function for the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method. So for each element `x` in `diceScores` this callback function checks whether `x` is equal to the `maxScore` i.e **6** and adds it to a the new array created by the `filter` method if the condition evaluates to true. Since 2 elements will pass this test therefore we can conclude that there's a tie

Comment: thanks! Just to double confirm, `diceScores.filter(x => x === maxScore)` creates an array of the numbers that are equal to `maxScore`?

Comment: Absolutely correct. Check the documentation for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var diceScores = [2, 3, 5, 5];
var highest = Math.max.apply(null, diceScores);
var count=0;
for (var i = 0; i < diceScores.length; i++) {
    if (highest==diceScores[i]){
        count = count + 1;
        if (count>1){
            // there are more than one high occurrence
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const diceResult = [1, 6, 3, 6]

diceResult.sort((a,b) => b - a)

const max = diceResult[0]

const tie = diceResult[0] === diceResult[1]

console.log(max)
console.log(tie)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also use a map to keep the score, it will be easier the record frequency of every score. *(just an idea)*

```js
const diceScores = {3:1, 5:1, 6:2};
const highestScore = Math.max(...Reflect.ownKeys(diceScores));
const frequecy = diceScores[highestScore]
console.log(highestScore, frequecy)
```

if `(Reflect.ownKeys(diceScores).length < 4)` // you can be sure something is repeated

```
(Reflect.ownKeys(diceScores).forEach((score)=>{
  // diceScores[score] will give you frequency of particular score

})
```

all these examples are just an idea, it might not be useful in your use-case but it will help to extend the functionality